# IF Statement with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to use if statements with 2 criteria to determine if a Variation Level value of 0) is NEW or EXISTING based on whether or not there is data in the "Prev" column for that variation's parts (Level values 1-4). Each variation may contain 1 or more parts, and I am unsure of how to tell Excel how to highlight only the New Variation Rows, based on the below logical question and example.

```
Column A Header= EXISTING/NEW
Column B Header= Group
Column C Header= Div
Column D Header= Rev
Column E Header= Level
Column F Header= Part Number
Column G Header= Quantity
Column H Header= Prev
```

[image]

The question I want to answer is: If column E (Level)="group code" or "variation" look to see if there is data in column Prev.  If there are any blank cells in column H Prev [not at the Variation or Group Code level], then this is a NEW variation.  If all the parts in column F have a value greater than 0 in column Prev, then that variation is EXISTING.and all the parts in that variation cells in Column H (Prev) contains any value >0 then [in row containing Variation] "Existing","New". ; AND when the next "Group Code" or "Variation" is reached in column E (Level)

My current If statement looks like this:

```
=IF(E2="Group Code","Group Code",IF(AND(ISBLANK(H3),(E2)="Variation"),"NEW","EXISTING"))
```

This is my data:

```
EXISTING / NEW  Group   Div Rev Level   Part Number Quantity Prev
Group Code  8200            Group Code  1234    0   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  Variation       1111-01-AA  0   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   1986
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1   1989
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   1986
NEW 8200    1   AB  Variation       2222-01-AA  0   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   
EXISTING    8200    1   AC  Variation       3333-01-AA  0   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   1985
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1    
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   2000
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   1532
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1    
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   1986
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1   1989
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   4512
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   1986
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1   1989
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   
EXISTING    8200    1   AC  Variation       3333-01-AA  0   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   4135
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               12121-21212 1   4987
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               23232-31313 1   
EXISTING    8200    1   AA  1               11111-11111 1   3587
```

Comment: what is your current formula not doing that you want it to do? The statement in *The question I want to answer is:* paragraph is not very clear ... maybe you can bullet point your logic, but even more clearly.

Comment: Is the problem with `H3` should it be `H2`?

Comment: Hi Scott: Sorry for the confusion.  Let me try again.

Comment: Hi Scott: Sorry. Let me try again. 1. The hierarchy structure is like a catalog system - Top level = Group Code / Next Level = Variation [both of these will have a qty of 0] / Next P/N Level will be 1 or greater, and varies from variation to variation. Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is: 1st determine which rows are Variations.  For each of the variation's p/n's any blanks at the p/n level, the variation will be a new one. If all p/n's reference a project in the "Prev" column, it's Existing. The data shown above is incorrect in column A. My if stmnt only looked in 1 row below.

Comment: My current statement only looks to the line below the line item above it.  Since Variations can have different numbers of parts, if there is a new part [no data in Prev column next to it], it doesn't catch all part number blanks below the first one below Variation.